# How to read unknown number of floats from a file?

Tags: c, arrays, file, numbers, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C dynamically growing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array)

I have a program and I need to read floats from a file. Each line is one float number. The problem is that this file may be very large

```
 float tab[1000];     
 
 f = fopen ("data.txt", "r");
 i=0;   
 while (feof(f) == 0) {        
   fscanf (f, "%f\n", &tab[i]);                
   i++;    
 }
```

How may I change size of array dynamicaly if it's too small?

Comment: This should definitely be closed for a duplicate: what are general idioms for handling growing arrays in C?

Comment: the conversion specifier to read `float` is `f` not `d`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294396/reallocating-an-array-c99 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338431/dynamic-array-using-ansi-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just start with a decent size, `malloc`, then `realloc` as you go if needed.

```
double *tab;
int num = 1000;

tab = malloc(num * sizeof *tab);

while (..) {
    if (i >= num)
        num *= 2;

    tab = realloc(tab, num * sizeof *tab);
    /* ... */
}
```

- You should try an initial size that covers most inputs without requiring too much memory
- You can try different realloc strategies, doubling the size is just one
- You should probably **check the result of `malloc` and `realloc`**

Answer (score 3):

If you need them all in memory at the same time, the `malloc` and `realloc`, as @cnicutar suggests, is probably the best solution.

But for many problems, you only really need to process one value at a time.  Just continue reading until you reach the end of the file.  It depends on the nature of the problem.

And you should correct several problems in your code:

- `"%d"` expects an `int*` argument; use `"%f"` to read `float` data.
- Don't use `feof(f)` to detect the end of the file.  Check the value returned by `fscanf()` (or whatever input routine you're using).  `feof()` is used to distinguish between a normal end-of-file condition and an error condition, and should be used only after an input function has already told you that it's run out of data.

Comment: *Don't use feof(f) to detect the end of the file* +1, solid advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the memory manually using `malloc`. If you buffer gets to small call `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of an array dynamically if it is allocated on the stack. You need something like this:

```
tab = calloc(1000, sizeof(float));

...

// need to resize
tmp = realloc(tab, (1000 + NUM_NEW_ELEMENTS) * sizeof(float));
if (tmp != NULL)
  tab = tmp;
```

Comment: `calloc()` sets the allocated space to all-bits-zero, which is often wasteful.  The standard doesn't guarantee that a floating-point 0.0 is represented as all-bits-zero, and if your code is written properly you won't be referring to any elements of the array until you've assigned values to them yourself.  `float *tab; tab = malloc(1000 * sizeof *tab);` is cleaner.  (Or you can just initialize `tab` to `NULL` and use `realloc()` for *every* allocation.)